# How to debug doctrine:schema:update

Tags: debugging, symfony, doctrine-orm

I running schema update for Symfony2 gives:

```
Warning: class_parents(): Class Tg\UserBunde\Entity\Person does not exist and could not be loaded in /vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 223
```

The Person class was in one bundle, then I moved it to a new bundle and updated the two assocations it had to the correct relative bundles, e.g.:

```
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\Tg\BlogBundle\Entity\Author", mappedBy="person")
 */
private $author;
```

I understand something must be wrong, but I have absolutely no clue where the error is. Getting the line in the factory class is obviously useless; so how can i find the location of the error?

Comment: Yes, the namespace is also updated, before anyone asks that. All namespacing is correct everywhere. The q is the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming UserBundle is the *old* one and BlogBundle is the *new* (correct) one?

Have you cleared caches and generated new proxies (orm:generate-proxies)? Cached metadata or outdated proxies could be the cause for it to try looking for the old incorrect entity.

Comment: I can't find that command. The `generate:entities` completes successfully. I did this:
`php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
No entries to be deleted.` Even cleared the cache folder and the error persists.

Comment: Actually UserBundle is the new one. Blogbundle already existed. I'm moving Person out of the MainBundle and want to rename it to User after successfully moving it.

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie the fact it's complaining about not finding the _new_ one would lead me to believe that a) autoloader is not configured correctly b) the file is in wrong place or has the wrong name c) the namespace or class name or such in the file itself is wrong

Comment: there was a typo, and overlooked it 3days straight. FML. At least the question is sort of solved, as I actually picked up the typo in the terminal exception.

Answer (score 0):

This permission change worked for me:

`chmod 777 app/console`

Comment: Hi Michael, that didn't work; think that helps mostly the bin/vendors update command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you override `__construct` and forget add `parent::__construct`

Comment: Hi nucleartux, that didn't work; I'm not sure how that affects the notation or assocation.